# How to display different text to the item that is in a listbox

Tags: c#

How can I display a definition instead of the text in a list when i press a button

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Opportunity cost");
        listBox1.Items.Add("consumer surplusSurplus");
        listBox1.Items.Add("inflation");
    }           

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Object obj in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a DataSource to show one thing and have another available to code?  Its not clear what you are after because there arent 2 of anything there (except maybe surplussurplus).  please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The easiest way is to create a simple class to hold the actual data (your string) and override the `ToString()` in the class.

Comment: Are you actually intending to add three new items to the list box when the user (or program) changes the selected item in the list?  You may be should place the three `listBox.Items.Add()` into the Load or Init event of the page.